# Create object or array to process a multistep form

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, javascript-objects

I'm creating a multistep form where I can write a form name, add steps and input types dinamically into the form, then generate an array or object (I'm not sure which one in my case would be the best) from that form, looping through the steps and getting the info of each input type, etc. To finally, send that object or array to PHP via Ajax.

Now, I'm stock trying to generate the array or object because I'm not sure which one is the best and don't know how to generate it.

What I think I need, would be:

```
var form = {

    idForm: "form-" + Date.now(),
    name: whatever you want, //get from the form
    steps: {
        0: {
           idStep: "step-" + Date.now(),
           name: get from form,
           fields: {
                0: {
                   idField: "field-" + Date.now(),
                   label: field 1,
                   placeholder: Enter data,
                   name: field 1,
                   required: true,
                   type: text,
                   options: {...} // this one should be added if type is a select, radio or checkbox.
                },
                1: {...},
                2{...}
           }
        },
        1: {...},
        2: {...}
    }

}
```

Any hint about how to generate it? any tip is welcome.

**Edited:**
After some research I could finally generate the object I have above, I just had to make a normal loop through the steps to get each information I need (**I use jquery .each()**). So to populate the object I did something like this:

```
formObj = {} // create an object

//create the node 'form' in the object and populate with id and name.
formObj.form = { id: "form-"+Date.now(), name: formName.val() };

//then create an array of steps inside the form node            
formObj["form"]["steps"] = [];
```

and so on, that way I generated the object.

When I make a print_r in php to check:

```
Array
(
    [form] => Array
        (
            [id] => form-1497888655149
            [name] => formulario 1
            [steps] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => step 1
                            [idStep] => step-1497886778424
                            [fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [idField] => input-1497886779390
                                            [label] => txéxt1
                                            [name] => null
                                            [required] => true
                                            [type] => text
                                            [options] => null
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: *whatever you want* will throw a syntax error. At least provide a valid form tree...

Comment: @Jonasw what you mean? because I forgot the comma?

Comment: There are numerous form builder scripts around...examine how they work

Answer (score 1):

## Recommendation: JSON

Since both PHP and JavaScript have fully compatible JSON capabilities, and JSON is great for passing data over HTTP, I personally use it alot, with ease.

Say your JS object looks like;

```
var foo = { "a": 1, "b": 2, c: [ 1, 2, 3, { erm: "dunno" } ] };
```

you can simply:

```
JSON.stringify( foo );
```

and get something like:

```
"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":[1,2,3,{\"erm\":\"dunno\"}]}"
```

which you can send to your PHP, which can:

```
json_decode( $foo, true );
```

to get an associative array like:

```
array (
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => array (
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 3,
        3 => array (
            'erm' => 'dunno',
        ),
    ),
)
```

which can be used in all the ways you'd expect, then if needed:

```
json_encode( $foo, JSON_HEX_TAG |
                   JSON_HEX_APOS |
                   JSON_HEX_QUOT |
                   JSON_HEX_AMP |
                   JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

will put it back to a *safe* string again.

See [JavaScript JSON on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and [PHP JSON on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

Feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: Thanks so much Fred for helping, I understand what you are recommending. Now my problem is how to generate that object, since I am not sure how to populate it with the info from the form, steps and fields inside the steps.

Comment: At this time, you've only shown an example object notation called "form". Am I right to assume you have some HTML to match? If so please show us. If not, that's where we'll need to start. Secondly, you'll need to read the form to create an object to send, or simply submit the form urlencoded (pretty much default for decades). Without seeing more of what you're working with ([minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), it will be almost impossible to guide you further. FYI: I'll be sleeping soon.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to write that part. Anyways, I could finally generate the object and send it to PHP with Ajax, but now I don't know how to access to that info, everytime I get " Array to string conversion in" or "Undefined offset: 0 in"

Comment: @DanielSoublett - Again; in order to help with why your (presumably) PHP isn't working (the accessing part), we would have to see it. There could be any number of reasons.